# iOS: Auto Layout: Two buttons side-by-side when there's enough space, otherwise on top of one another

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Looking for an auto layout solution where two buttons lie side-by-side when there is enough space to do so, but otherwise (when the view is displayed with limited width) rest on top of one another.

I don't even know where to begin to think this through with auto layout. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808739/how-to-use-autolayout-to-position-uibuttons-in-horizontal-lines-wrapping-left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine this being a combo between autolayout and an NSLayoutConstraint property constant, whereby you set the constraints in IB/Storyboard, and click-drag the trailing space to container constraint for each uibutton onto a viewcontroller as some named IBOutlet property. (i.e. myconstraint1, myconstraint2.)

Then, upon some condition where you can determine the limited width (rotation event, adding a new view?), you set the two constraint constants to the same value, e.g. self.myconstraint1.constant = self.myconstraint2.constant = someValue.

Not knowing the code, I can't tell you the math of course, nor would I know what to reset things to, but otherwise, programmatically setting the nslayoucontraint.constant should give you the desired effect of two uibutton views overlapping one another horizontally.

Similarly, to move them so the Y coordinates differ, you use a similar approach with the vertical spacing to bottom layout constraint for one or both of the buttons.

Comment: I would also recommend adding an object to your storyboard (it's in the list with views labels etc on the right) and turn it into a ResizeHandler. So you won't swamp your main ViewController with all those functions and outlets only being used for the specific case of elastic layouts.

Comment: Yup, that worked. In my storyboard I created the buttons side by side. The key is to create trailing constraints to superview (container) for each of the buttons. And create bottom (or top) constraints for each as well. Connect the constraints to outlets so you can reference them from your code. Then whenever you want the buttons to be on top of one another (instead of side by side) set both the trailing constraints to the same value and offset the buttons vertically by setting the bottom constraints to different values. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Learning to merge autolayout with nslayoutconstraint constants really helped expand how I conceptualized design possibilities on mobile devices.