# Add subviews and use AutoLayout to align leading edge with superview AND wrap views

Tags: swift, uiview, xcode6, autolayout

In swift, I'm adding sub-views programmatically via a button. The sub-views can be as thin as 256 points, which means they could appear horizontally once on an iPhone and 3 times on an iPad in portrait. In landscape, they could fit twice across a 4 inch iphone in landscape, or four times on an iPad. Ultimately, I'd like any number of sub-views to appear horizontally, aligned to the leading edge (left) of the super-view in order from 1st to last, but **wrapping according to device size and rotation,** and the button to appear below the last sub-view added.

I'd have thought this would be a fairly common design pattern for iOS - fully covered by an adaptive system like Auto-layout - but I can't find a clear example of how to do this in code. I've watched all the WWDC videos on Auto-layout and tried a few approaches, but solutions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808739/how-to-use-autolayout-to-position-uibuttons-in-horizontal-lines-wrapping-left?lq=1), seem to depend upon the orientation as the view is added, rather than responding to changes in orientation. I must be using the wrong search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is going to be to use a [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html) with a custom layout. Auto layout does not have the concept of a content flow, only dynamic sizing.

Alternatively, you can make your interface in HTMl and display it in a [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html).

Comment: Thanks - I'll have to learn how to do that, and will then mark the question as answered.